# Javadoc comments for simple constructors. Needed or needless?

Tags: java, javadoc

Given the following code snippet:

```
/**
 * Initializes a new instance.
 *
 */
public Collector() {
    this.map = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Please concentrate on the *Javadoc comment*: There does not happen very much in this constructor. So, whats the proper way to write Javadoc for it? As is shown above? That would be perfectly accurate but **superfluous** at the same time, because a constructor is meant to initialize a new instance.

So, on one hand, we do not want to write redundant information in Javadoc comments, on the other hand, there has to be a Javadoc comment (has it?).

So, in short, how to write **meaningfull, not redundant** Javadoc in such situations?

Comment: I would rather have a *javadoc comment* which goes like - *The class X has only default constructor which initializes a hashMap HM which stores key k  and value V for operation O*

Comment: Straight from Oracle - [Documenting Default Constructors](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#defaultconstructors).

Comment: If the comment is just what you posted: I would love to see the dude that doesn't know that a constructor initializes a new instance, but is smart enough to check the JavaDoc.

Comment: Plus 1 for mentioning meaningless comment. Why vote for closing?

Comment: BTW, if you initialize the map inline (in the place of declaration), you can delete this explicit constructor altogether and have only the default one.

Comment: I'm working with forms in the play framework and you sometimes NEED to have a default, empty constructor, else play breaks. This is something I would definitly mention in the javadoc comment for a default constructor so nobody removes the seemingly useless constructor. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117355/play-framework-error-on-bindrequest

Comment: I would add such comment in a java library with public API, but I wouldn't add this comment in a regular project.

Comment: Since it's already on hold anyhow: IMH opinion (!), there is hardly a reason to differentiate between a "library" or a "regular project" (what IS the difference, after all?). I personally don't like JavaDocs where certain elements do not have a comment at all - even if it's only the default constructors. So I think something like `/** Default constructor */ public Foo(){}` is perfectly feasible. People may consider it as "redundant", but it's part of the documentation of the public API. (and when there also is a non-default-constructor, documenting the default one becomes mandatory - IMHO)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on who is the reader of the code and how obvious the constructor's functionality is. Either the javadoc is the only source of information for a reader (closed-source), or the reader can easily grasp what's going on in detail from the source. In our projects, we do not javadoc obvious functionality at all. When some formalism requires javadoc, we simply use /** Constructor. */ to just satisfy the formalism.